# Конструктор копирования на динамических объектах класса

Tags: c++

Есть класс "факультет", нужно создать конструктор копирования для обычных и динамических объектов. Для обычных конструктор работает без привязки, а вот для "динамических" два объекта сливаются в один. Код для проверки ниже.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

class Faculty
{
public:
    // constructors & destructor

    // constructor without variables
    Faculty() {
        number = NULL;
    }
    // constructor to set fields
    Faculty(int faculty_number) {
        number = faculty_number;
    }
    // copy constructor
    Faculty(const Faculty& ref_point) {
        number = ref_point.number;
    }

    // destructor
    ~Faculty() {
        std::cout << " ~ class object has been destroyed\n";
    }

    // set & get methods
    void set_number(int faculty_number) {
        number = faculty_number;
    }
    int get_number() {
        return number;
    }
    

    // class data output
    void show_data() {
        std::cout << " ~ Faculty number = " << number << "\n";
    }

private:
    // fields 
    int number; 
};

int main()
{
    // for localization
    SetConsoleOutputCP(1251);
    SetConsoleCP(1251);

    std::cout << "Задаем значение st_Obj1 и копируем его конструктором в новый st_Obj2\n";
    Faculty st_Obj1(1);
    Faculty st_Obj2 = st_Obj1;
    std::cout << "st_Obj1.number = ";
    st_Obj1.show_data();
    std::cout << "st_Obj2.number = ";
    st_Obj2.show_data();
    std::cout << "Изменяем поле st_Obj1 и проверяем все объекты на изменения\n";
    st_Obj1.set_number(2);
    std::cout << "st_Obj1.number = ";
    st_Obj1.show_data();
    std::cout << "st_Obj2.number = ";
    st_Obj2.show_data();
    std::cout << "Задаем значение dynamic_Obj1 и копируем его конструктором в новый dynamic_Obj2\n";
    Faculty* dynamic_Obj1 = new Faculty(1);
    Faculty* dynamic_Obj2 = dynamic_Obj1;   // это не правильно, усвоил
    // Faculty* dynamic_Obj2 = new Faculty() <- но как тогда вызвать конструктор копирования
    std::cout << "dynamic_Obj1.number = ";
    dynamic_Obj1->show_data();
    std::cout << "dynamic_Obj2.number = ";
    dynamic_Obj2->show_data();
    std::cout << "Изменяем поле dynamic_Obj1 и проверяем все объекты на изменения\n";
    dynamic_Obj1->set_number(2);
    std::cout << "dynamic_Obj1.number = ";
    dynamic_Obj1->show_data();
    std::cout << "dynamic_Obj2.number = ";
    dynamic_Obj2->show_data();

    delete dynamic_Obj1;
    delete dynamic_Obj2;
    return 0;
}
```

Только два объекта освобождают память до появления ошибки. Не понимаю как создать "конструктор копирования" во втором случае.

[image: консоль]

Comment: Во-первых тут полный зашквар с терминологией. Статический и динамический тип - это вообще про другое. `Faculty st_Obj2` и `Faculty *dynamic_Obj2` являются объектами с автоматическим временем хранения. А, объекты, выделенные с помощью `new` являются объектами с динамическим временем хранения. Во-вторых вызов конструктора копирования у объекта с типом `Faculty *` никогда не приводит к вызову конструктора копирования неродственного типа `Faculty`. В-третьих, приведенный кусок кода не является [mcve] чтобы утверждать, что тут есть "нарушение доступа".

Comment: исправил, надеюсь теперь понятно описал суть проблемы.

Comment: Еще раз - объекты с динамическим временем хранения - это которые созданы при помощи `new`. В приведенном коде `new` вызывается один раз - создается один объект с динамическим временем хранения. Хотите создать еще один - вызывайте `new` еще раз. И да, количество `delete` должно равняться количеству `new`.

Comment: это понятно, вопрос в том как вызвать из него конструктор копирования?

Comment: вот эта строка `Faculty st_Obj2 = st_Obj1;` и вызывает конструктор копирования.

Comment: я это писал, я знаю что это вызывает конструктор копирования, вопрос состоит в том как вызвать его здесь `Faculty* dynamic_Obj2 = new Faculty()`

Comment: пропишите `operator=`, иначе Вас будут ждать новые приключения:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы, наверное, хотите второй объект через `new`, но копию первого?

```
Faculty* dynamic_Obj1 = new Faculty(1);
Faculty* dynamic_Obj2 = new Faculty(*dynamic_Obj1);
```

Comment: Пусть кремний, а так же ноль и единица подарят вам счастье, спасибо добрый человек :)